# Use For loop inside JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you use a `for` loop in JSX like this?
Or rather, what is the propper way to write a `for` like this?

```
var graph = 
        <div className={"chartContent"}>

        .
        .
        .

            <div className="panel">
                {DataRows.forEach(function(entry) &&
                    <div className="col-sm-2 graphPanel graphPanelExtra">
                        <div className="panel panel-primary">
                            <div>entry</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}

            </div>
        </div>;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) so you're actually returning the elements. A foreach doesn't return anything. Your use of `&&` was also invalid.

```
var graph = 
        <div className="chartContent">
            <div className="panel">
                {DataRows.map(entry =>
                    <div key={entry.id} className="col-sm-2 graphPanel graphPanelExtra">
                        <div className="panel panel-primary">
                            <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>entry</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>;
```

Note that I added a `key` property - for react to optimise rendering of an array of elements each item should have a unique key (that isn't just the numeric index).

Comment: Hi Dominic.  If its `(entry)` a Key Value pair. How do you seperate the values? Please.

Comment: entry is an object? In that case you could do `Object.keys(entry).map(...`

Comment: Yeah, sorry. just saw that. thanks

Comment: map is the correct way to go as it returns a modified array.

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` does not return anything. You wont see any results out of it. Instead you could use `.map` e.g.

```
 {
     DataRows.map(function (entry) {
             return <div className="col-sm-2 graphPanel graphPanelExtra">
                        <div className="panel panel-primary">
                            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>entry</div>
                        </div> < /div>
                })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a `forEach` loop you can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var graph = 
    <div className={"chartContent"}>

    .
    .
    .

        <div className="panel">
            {DataRows.map((entry) => (
                <div className="col-sm-2 graphPanel graphPanelExtra">
                    <div className="panel panel-primary">
                        <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>entry</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               )
            )}

        </div>
    </div>;
```